# PowerShell command: Feature Delegation settings : Delegate an Application Feature as Read/Write

Tags: authentication, iis

Looking for Power shell script or command, which change the value of "Authentication - Anonymous" from 'Read Only' to 'Read/Write' in Feature Delegation ->IIS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After some searching on Google, I found this.  It worked for me.

```
appcmd unlock config /section:anonymousAuthentication
```

Appcmd, of course, needs to be in your path.  It is usually in %windir%\system32\inetsrv.